# How to Properly set base_url() in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on an application based on codeigniter, i have created a global layout page on that i page i have included all the css, js and other images that is in assets folder in codeigniter root.

i have included those files like below code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/front/website/static/fonts/icomoon-greycom/css/style.css">
```

when i visit homepage https://mypage.com, it works fine
it loads those files as

```
https://mypage.com/assets/front/website/static/font/icomoon-greycom/css/style.css
```

but when i visit other links like.

https://mypage.com/region/india

den it load

```
https://mypage.com/region/india/assets/front/wesbite/static/font/icon-greycom/css/style.css
```

but i want it should load only `https://mypage.com/assets/assets/front/wesbite/static/font/icon-greycom/css/style.css`

in my config.php page

```
$config['base_url'] = "https://www.mypage.com/";
```

how to solve this issue.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url

Comment: there's no problem on how you link your stylesheet. make sure you load the helper url too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/front/website/static/fonts/icomoon-greycom/css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the asset path *inside* the `base_url` function (as per the [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url)).

e.g.

`<?php echo base_url('assets/front/website/static/fonts/icomoon-greycom/css/style.css'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Can Use

```
href="<?php echo base_url().'assets/front/website/static/fonts/icomoon-greycom/css/style.css'; ?>"
```